# Azure Build Pipeline not falling into correct queue

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am creating a build pipeline using YAML for the first time and I have set the pool to be the Default pool with holds my self hosted windows agent - `AzureDevOpsAgent001`. This agent is located on a Windows 2012 R2 Server.

However when I run this build definition it seems to be falling into the `Host Ubuntu 1604` queue. Therefor will not do anything as its waiting for a agent not available.

**YAML:**

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need check if the **Default agent pool for YAML** of your pipeline is Host Ubuntu 1604.

**Edit** your yml pipeline, in the right top corner click the **3 dots** and select **Triggers**, go the **Yaml** page. And the check if the default agent pool has be set to Host Ubuntu 1604. 
[image]